# How can a child class inherit a class method from its parent that gets a class variable from the child in python?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, class-method, class-variables

I have a code here where I define a parent class with class methods and class variables:

```
class Parent:
    var1 = 'foo'
    var2 = 'bar'
    
    def getVar1Var2AsString(self):
        return f'{Parent.getVar1()}_{Parent.getVar2()}'

    @classmethod
    def getVar1(cls):
        return cls.var1

    @classmethod
    def getVar2(cls):
        return cls.var2
```

And then, I have a code where I define the child class:

```
class Child(Parent):
    var1 = 'banana'
    var2 = 'apple'
```

And then I run:

```
child = Child()
output = child.getVar1Var2AsString()
print(output)
```

I expected that the output would return `banana_apple`, but it returns `foo_bar` instead.

How can I get the result I expect? I'm kind of new in OOP.

Comment: That's because you hard-coded references to `Parent` in the method, instead of using `self.getVar1` and `self.getVar2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `getVar1Var2AsString`, when you call `Parent.getVar1()`, you do so without any reference to the current object or its class. It *always* looks up the methods on `Parent`. If you want to look up the methods in the current object's class, use `self.getVar1()`. You also don't need the getter methods at all, you can just use `self.var1` and `self.var2`.

Comment: It's not the lookup that matters so much as the implicit argument passed to the function when the class method gets called. If `self` is an instance of `Child`, then `self.getVar1()` is equivalent to `Parent.__dict__['getVar1'](Child)` instead of `Parent.__dict__['getVar1'](Parent)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't knew it would be possible to access class variables from the object. It worked out very well here for me. Thanks again.

Comment: @caio.valente14 think about it this way - methods are just class variables!

Answer (score 0):

The inheritance is fine, it's the variable access that's wrong. In `getVar1Var2AsString`, when you write `Parent`, that always refers to `Parent` (of course), not the class of `self`, which can be got with `type(self)`. Or if you'd rather look up the class variables on the instance, just use `self`.

By the way, I don't think the getters add anything here.

So:

```
def getVar1Var2AsString(self):
    return f'{type(self).var1}_{type(self).var2}'
```

Or, since `self` is only being used to look up its class, you could make it a class method:

```
@classmethod
def getVar1Var2AsString(cls):
    return f'{cls.var1}_{cls.var2}'
```

---

To be clear, it looks like you thought `cls` in a `classmethod` would take the value of `type(self)`, but that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to get `foo_bar` in case the object is an instance of the `Parent` class and `banana_apple` in case it's an instance of the `Child` class you can do this by changing your `getVar1Var2AsString` to

```
@classmethod
def getVar1Var2AsString(cls):
    return f"{cls.getVar1()}_{cls.getVar2()}"
```

This way the values of the corresponding class are used to generate the output.